# Two giant men fighting in the middle of a fake city

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

Based only on this scene I'm trying to remember a movie:

Two giant men are fighting in the middle of a fake city, with fake buildings and stuff. There is not a lot of CGI or special effects, the buildings and city look closely to the buildings in a Power rangers megazord fight.

These two men faces and body also look fake, kinda like puppets. One guy is bald and the other is *probably* Chinese.

In the fight they fall over the buildings, streets, their fight style also look strange. It's a regular fight, with punches and kicks, vin diesel style, but their moves are slowed because they are so big.

I don't remember if they took some drugs before the fight scene, or it was only a director's choice to have this fight scene like this.

I'm only remembering this scene but the rest of the movie seems to be normal. Only this fight scene has this style.

- Language: Saw it dubbed in my language (Portuguese) but it was certainly a Hollywood movie.
- Release year: 2005-2014
- Type: Action Movie
- Where I saw: Probably rented a DVD or watched on television.

Comment: is there anything else about the movie's plot that you remember?

Comment: @DForck42 Not really, I'm only remembering this scene =/

Comment: any other details you can add will help.  as such, it's pretty vague

Comment: You need to provide more info. What about those men how looks like (normal clothes any costume)? What about the fight? Punching match, Martial arts, special effects?

Comment: I know Crank 2 is the answer, but I just wanted to point out that Hot Fuzz has a good fight in a miniature city as well :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Crank 2 - High Voltage](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt1121931/) from 2009 starring Jason Statham.

Here is the fight scene:

Comment: I didn't exactly regret never seeing this movie, but having seen the first Crank and knowing this is what became of its sequel, I am now *happy with the choice that I made.* =P

Comment: Amazing pull, Francisco V.! I saw this movie (and loved it) but didn't remember this scene at all.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I thought it couldn't get worse, and then one of them started flying. I am so glad I never heard of this film before.

Comment: This film is not meant to be taken seriously, if you don't it is very enjoyable.